# Running the browser (not headlessly) on the VM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

The script below runs the Firefox driver on native mode. It is located on a VirtualBox VM, which I've made an SSH connection to it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=caps)
browser.get('https://example.com')
```

It works fine within the VM terminal itself, but this error would show up when I run it through the SSH connection.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firefox.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=caps)
  File "/home/twilight/miniconda3/envs/openwpm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/twilight/miniconda3/envs/openwpm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/twilight/miniconda3/envs/openwpm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/twilight/miniconda3/envs/openwpm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/twilight/miniconda3/envs/openwpm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Formerly, I was able to run the browser remotely (on the VM itself), so I know it is possible.

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Does the firefox webdriver is in the path when running via ssh?

Comment: Yes, it is listening, using geckodriver command; plus why it works for headless mode?

Comment: Did you use`ssh -X`?

Comment: No, why should I? Since I don't want to run the GUI on my host device.

Comment: 2 things to check.....if you are NOT running it headless, this could be the issue if the VM doesn't have a display (Ubuntu etc...).  Second thing, make sure the version of Gecko Driver matches the correct FireFox browser version on that machine if the first issue mentioned is not applicable

Comment: Indeed VM has a display (it is Ubuntu desktop). I think the problem stems from the Display options on the SSH terminal. BTW, Thank you all for your comments